# How do I stub window.innerWidth/innerHeight with sinon?

Tags: javascript, sinon

I can't seem to figure out how to stub the innerWidth and innerHeight properties using sinon. Does anyone know what the syntax is or if it's even possible?

Souce code:

```
describe('test', () => {
  let sandbox;

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    sandbox.stub(window, "innerWidth").get(() => 1000);
    sandbox.stub(window, "innerHeight").get(() => 1000);
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should do a thing', () => {
    console.log(window.innerWidth); // 1024
    console.log(window.innerHeight); // 768
  });
});
```

Console output:

```
 PASS  src/components/Tooltip/tests/index.test.js
  test
    ✓ should do a thing (2ms)

  console.log src/components/Tooltip/tests/index.test.js:58
    1024

  console.log src/components/Tooltip/tests/index.test.js:59
    768

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.573s, estimated 1s
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I solve it as below:

`window.innerWidth = 1280;`

not sure whether this is the best way but it solves my problem.

If you had found the other way then please share.